# Top 2 offers with sum of all offers with description

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can someone please tell how can I get the results as below. (*with description* for the top 2 cash offers)

Using dense_rank function where rank <=2 will give me top 2 offers.

I am also looking to get 'total_offer' which should be sum of 'offer1' and 'offer2'. when there is no offer2 ( eg:taurus) 'total offer' should be 'offer1' and 'null' for 'offer2'

Input:

```
customer    make    zipcode offer notes  
mark        focus   101     250   cash  
mark        focus   101     2500  appreciation cash  
mark        focus   101     1000  cash  
mark        focus   101     1500  cash offer  

henry       520i    21405   500  cash offer  
henry       520i    21405   100  cash  
henry       520i    21405   750  appreciation cash  
henry       520i    21405   100  cash  

mark        taurus  48360   250    appreciation cash  

mark        mustang 730     500  cash  
mark        mustang 730     1000  Cash offer  
mark        mustang 730     1250  appreciation cash
```

Desired Output:

```
| CUSTOMER | MAKE    | ZIPCODE | TOP_OFFER1 | NOTES1            | TOP_OFFER2 | NOTES2     | Total_offer   
| henry    | 520i    | 21405   | 750        | appreciation cash | 500        | cash offer | 1250    
| mark     | focus   | 101     | 2500       | appreciation cash | 1500       | cash offer | 4000  
| mark     | mustang | 730     | 1250       | appreciation cash | 1000       | cash offer | 2250    
| mark     | taurus  | 48360   | 250        | appreciation cash | NULL       | 250        |
```

Thanks

PS:

The link below tells me that dense_rank need to be performed to get top 2 offers.
([Top 2 offers with sum of all offers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661571/top-2-offers-with-sum-of-all-offers))

Answer (score 0):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer, make, zipcode,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then offer end) as offer1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then notes end) as notes1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then offer end) as offer2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then notes end) as notes2,
       sum(offer) as total_offer
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, make, zipcode order by offer desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by customer, make, zipcode;
```

Comment: The output is coming up in 2 rows instead of 1 row

Comment: | henry | 520i | 21405 | 750  | appreciation cash | 500 | cash offer | 1250

Comment: | henry | 520i | 21405 | 750  | appreciation cash

Comment: | henry | 520i | 21405 | 500  | cash offer

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  There should only be one row for each combination of customer/make/zipcode.